# xslt: Copy node if Value like

Tags: xml, xslt

i want to use xslt to transform a xml to an other. In my case i got a List with many products but i only need one product of them in a new xml file.
I got this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data version="v1.0.0">
    <header>
        <field1>V1</field1>
        <generation_date>
            <date>10.07.2018</date>
            <time>11:19:42</time>
        </generation_date>
    </header>
    <brands />
    <products>
        <product>
            <id>1</id>
            <name>1</name>
            <test1>1</test1>
            <test2>1</test2>
        </product>
        <product>
            <id>2</id>
            <name>2</name>
            <test1>2</test1>
            <test2>2</test2>
        </product>
    </products>
</data>
```

and i need only products with id 1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data version="v1.0.0">
    <header>
        <field1>V1</field1>
        <generation_date>
            <date>10.07.2018</date>
            <time>11:19:42</time>
        </generation_date>
    </header>
    <brands />
    <products>
        <product>
            <id>1</id>
            <name>1</name>
            <test1>1</test1>
            <test2>1</test2>
        </product>
    </products>
</data>
```

but iam not able to do this by my own - can someone help me??

best regards,
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start with an `identity transform` template that copies all the input as is and then modify the `<product>` template to eliminate the ones having `id != '1'`.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <!-- identity transform template to copy input as is to output -->
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- remove <product> having id != 1 -->
    <xsl:template match="product[id != '1']" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output

```
<data version="v1.0.0">
    <header>
        <field1>V1</field1>
        <generation_date>
            <date>10.07.2018</date>
            <time>11:19:42</time>
        </generation_date>
    </header>
    <brands />
    <products>
        <product>
            <id>1</id>
            <name>1</name>
            <test1>1</test1>
            <test2>1</test2>
        </product>
    </products>
</data>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code copies everything from the input file except multiple product in products. If you want to check for the id you can do it by:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="product[id = '1']"/>
```

This code only applies products which have a node named id which content is '1'.
The template match on @* in my code means its matching on every attribute in a node too.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="* | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="products">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="product[1]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```